# Need help translating foo += (bar - foo) * qux; to Clojure

Tags: java, clojure, processing

I have the following code in Java/Processing

```
  posX += (targetX - posX) * easing;
  posY += (targetY - posY) * easing;
```

but I'm struggling to translate that to Clojure, any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: It's really hard to translate a couple of lines of imperative Java code (which are explicitly modifying state) to stateless, functional code. A better approach is to step back, look at the problem you're trying to solve or algorithm you're trying to implement, and ask yourself how you'd do it in a functional style. Transcribing Java to Clojure line-by-line seldom yields good results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your code snippet I'm guessing you are basically transforming a set of coordinates using another set and an easing factor.

I would define a function to encapsulate the transformation in the following way:

```
(defn ease-coord [factor src tgt]
  (+ src (* (- tgt src) factor)))

(defn ease [factor src tgt]
  (map (partial ease-coord factor) src tgt))

(ease 0.1 [1 2] [3 10])
;=> (1.2 2.8)
(ease 0.1 [1 2 3] [3 10 5])
;=> (1.2 2.8 3.2)
```

Note that the `ease` function actually works for vectors and lists that have any number of coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/matrix-api) if you are going to do a lot of work with vector maths. It provides vector overrides for all the common maths functions (+, -, * etc..), and allows you to work transparently with mathematical vectors that are expressed as regular Clojure vectors.

Here's what it might look like:

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix.operators)

(defn lerp [start end factor]
     (+ start (* (- end start) factor)))

(lerp [1 2] [10 10] 0.1)
=> [1.9 2.8]
```

If you care about performance, you can also use the [vectorz-clj](https://github.com/mikera/vectorz-clj) implementation, which enhances `core.matrix` with a specialised fast `Vector2` type for (x,y) co-ordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm learning clojure and this solution is in all likelihood not idiomatic.

```
;    Let *tx*, *ty* be your target coordinate
;    Let sx, sy be your starting coordinate
;    Let *eg* be your easing
    (def ^:dynamic *eg* 0.05)
    (def ^:dynamic *tx* 100)
    (def ^:dynamic *ty* 100)
    (defn next-position [[sx sy]] [(+ sx (* (- *tx* sx) *eg*)) (+ sy (* (- *ty* sy) *eg*))])
    (defn positions [[x y]] (iterate next-position [x y]))

; To get the next position
(next-position [5 6])

; To get the next 100 positions
(take 100 (positions [5 6]))
```

Answer (score 0):

What are posX, posY?

they can be atoms.

```
(def posX (atom 0))
(def posY (atom 0))
```

If you want to change posX, you can write a function

```
(defn update-posx 
  [targetX easing] 
  (swap! 
    posX 
    #(+ % (* (- targetX %) easing))))
```

An updating is something like

```
(update-posx 20 30)
```